# Bootstrap single full width column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a full width column that should not stack on small devices but stay with the same width. I am using bootstrap 4. This is my code,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class=""row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Welcome back User!</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But when I inspect there is a slight oveflow in small devices. How to fix this?

Comment: simply use `col-12` class to div

Comment: I tried.Still there is an overflow

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: You have a **typo**: `<div class="" row ">` - note the extra `"`. This means the row class is not getting applied so its negative margin isn't being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap `col-12` class or just use a simple div to make it full width everywhere.

Here is the working example using bootstrap `col-12` class:

```css
.col-12 {
    background-color: #dedede;
}

.content {
    background-color: #abaaba;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <h1>Welcome back User!</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- without using bootstrap -->

<div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome back User!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yah. It works here. But I am having trouble again. When I am going in inspect mode it works at some time and after without making any changes at all it again overflows. It seems to work well when minimize the chrome window. Any fixes

Comment: @RifkyNiyas This code will work in all modern browsers even in Internet Explorer. You can check above snippet example in different browsers. I think you may have some CSS inheritance issue in your application. If you share some more info then i can help you to resolve the issue you are facing.